# variable equals two single quotes?

Tags: javascript

I'm studying an existing JQuery file to learn from it, but I don't understand this line (despite a lot of searching on the internet):

```
var item = '';
```

There is no space between the quotes. Further into the function, *item* is set to equal the value of another variable plus an html character.

It seems logical to me to assume that this means *item* has a NULL value to begin with. However, from what I've read, you should set the variable equal to NULL for that, right?

Can someone please explain?

Thanks!

Comment: 10/10 would be trolled again

Comment: An empty string is not null.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was down-voted, nor do I understand "10/10 would be trolled again". Please explain so I can ask better questions next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to concatenate that variable and build a longer string you first need it to be a string and `''` represents an empty string which can often be a good starting point.

You can then do:

```
item += 'I get added to the string';
item += ' Me too, I am joining the string';
```

Comment: This is exactly what happens further into the code.

Comment: Right and it could be conditional so that the actual string used at the end may still be the empty string if conditions weren't met to add to it along the business logic path

Answer (score 4):

The author is initializing the variable as a string.

Comment: And a reason I often do that is for exactly why @charlietfl points out.